# no matching function for call to a function in merge sort

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to write a merge sort algorithm in **C++**.
If i try to compile the following code, i get the **error**:

*mergeSort.cpp:9:19: error: no matching function for call to 'merge(std::vector&, int&, int&, int&)'*

I tried everything in my knowledge to fix this problem and find similar ones online, but I can't figure it out on my own. Please help!

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

void sort(std::vector<int> v, int a, int b) {
    //if a == b the length of the subarray is one
    if (a != b) {
        int k = (a + b) / 2;
        sort(v, a, k);
        sort(v, k+1, b);
        merge(v, a, k, b); //this line gives out the error
    }
}

void merge(std::vector<int> &v, int &a, int &k, int &b) {
    std::vector<int> tempv;
    int tmpa = a;
    int tmpk = k;
    for (int i = 0; i < b-a; i++) {
        if (tmpa >= k-1) {
            tempv.push_back(v[tmpk]);
            tmpk++;
        }
        else if (tmpk >= b) {
            tempv.push_back(v[tmpk]);
            tmpk++;
        }
        else if (v[tmpa] < v[tmpk]) {
            tempv.push_back(v[tmpk]);
            tmpk++;
        }
        else {
            tempv.push_back(v[tmpk]);
            tmpk++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = a; i < b; i++) {
        v[i] = tempv[i-a];
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {2, 7, 1, 3, 4, 4};
    
    sort(v, 0, v.size()-1);
    
    for (int i: v) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You have to declare merge function before using in sort.

Comment: Note `(a + b)` may overflow, resulting in a failed sort.

Comment: Somehow no one has mentioned `std::merge`. Do not use that header. It brings in _everything_, if it works at all. You've encountered something that got you because of that.

Comment: @chris i didn't use "namespace std;", am I not free to choose the same function names then?

Comment: @derda, No, because argument-dependent lookup exists. Of course you can still name them the same, but yes, ADL will still find the `std` one, which can make for confusing errors if it's declared when it wouldn't otherwise be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this line before the sort function:

```
void merge(std::vector<int> &v, int &a, int &k, int &b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the `merge()` function before the definition of that, so just shift your merge() function before the sort() function.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you need to make sure the function declaration before it's used.

In your case, you used `merge` before any declaration and so the error.

To fix that, put this declaration at the front, before it is used in your `sort` function:

```
void merge(std::vector<int> &v, int &a, int &k, int &b);
```

Alternatively, you could move the whole `merge` function definition up front.

Btw, this code could overflow with the intermediate calculation `(a + b)`

```
int k = (a + b) / 2;      // could overflow
```

which could be improved by:

```
int k = a - (a - b) / 2;  // fine
```

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of `merge` is not visible at the point of usage. Declare the function before using it.

```
// Declare the function.
void merge(std::vector<int> &v, int &a, int &k, int &b);

void sort(std::vector<int> v, int a, int b) {
    //if a == b the length of the subarray is one
    if (a != b) {
        int k = (a + b) / 2;
        sort(v, a, k);
        sort(v, k+1, b);

        // Now you can use it.
        merge(v, a, k, b); //this line gives out the error
    }
}
```

On a more imporant note...

`sort` needs to accepts the vector by reference, not by value. Otherwise, the sorted object won't be visible in the calling function.

```
void sort(std::vector<int>& v, int a, int b) { ... }
//                       ^^^
```

As a matter of good coding practice, I recommend declaring all functions before defining and using them.

```
// Declare the functions.
void sort(std::vector<int>& v, int a, int b);
void merge(std::vector<int> &v, int &a, int &k, int &b);

// Define the functions.
void sort(std::vector<int>& v, int a, int b)
{
   ...
}

void merge(std::vector<int> &v, int &a, int &k, int &b)
{
   ...
}
```